# How could i append inputted text into a .txt file within an ASP.NET MVC project file?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am currently busy with a project which is suppose to take a user input from the 'categoryDescription' input text box and append it to an already created text file which i have put under the folder, 'app_data', saved under the name of 'category.txt'. I am very new to ASP.NET MVC and am rather lost to say the very least.. i am unsure as to where to go from here on-wards..

Below i have attached a code segment which is supposedly responsible for the appending of the input to the text file: (side note: this code falls under the 'Category.cshtml' view, controlled by 'CategoryController.cs')

```
@{
    var result = "";
    if (IsPost)
    {
        var description = Request["categoryDescription"];

        var userData = description + Environment.NewLine;

        var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Category.txt");
        File.WriteAllText(dataFile, userData);
        result = "Information Saved.";
    }
}
```

And hereafter is the code for the input and final if statement to check whether the 'IsPost' property has been submitted before i have started processing.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Categories"))
{
    <input id="categoryDescription " type="text" name="categoryDescription" />

    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>

}

@if (result != "")
{
    <p>Result: @result</p>
}
```

I apologize if i have been unable to explain any clearer, i will answer questions as soon as possible. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `WriteAllText` use [`AppendAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=netframework-4.8):

```
File.AppendAllText(dataFile, userData);
```